# UITapGesture doesn't work when I try to add it into a Custom UIView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitapgesturerecognizer

I use Xcode 15.1.

I create a CustomView to use in my project

```
class CustomView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var childView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    dprint("CustomView init frame")
    viewInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    dprint("CustomView init coder")
    viewInit()
}

func viewInit() {
    let xibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    addSubview(xibView)
}

}
```

So, I try to call this custom view inside my UIVIewController using the code:

```
    let cv = CustomView()
    self.view.addSubview(cv)
    HelperXib.setCenteredXibContraints(cv, self.view)

struch HelperXib {
  static func setCenteredXibContraints(_ sameView:UIView, _ parentView: UIView) {
    // for errorView message that show on center, example: AlertNoPixKey
    sameView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sameView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor),
        sameView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor),
    ])
  }
}
```

The view shows perfectly on my screen, then I try to use a code to use my one of my UIView(buttonView) inside the custom view to respond to tap events.

```
    let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChargeEnterDataViewController.redirectToMyKeys(_:)) )
    cv.buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)
    cv.buttonView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Unfortunatley, there's no response when I click the buttonView UIView on my screen.

How can I make it work?

--- EDIT #1 ---

I find something strange. I try to use

```
print("cv.frame.size: \(cv.frame.size)")
print("cv.buttonView.frame.size: \(cv.buttonView.frame.size)")
```

it shows this on Xcode console

```
cv.frame.size: (0.0, 0.0)
cv.buttonView.frame.size: (240.0, 49.0)
```

For some reason the cv UIView is getting 0.0 for width and height. Don't know why this is happening. Maybe this could be the reason because the tapGesture is not working.

--- EDIT #2 ---

I use the code

```
let cv = CustomView()
cv.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
cv.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
cv.backgroundColor = .blue
```

My this is the result

[image: https://snipboard.io/kaedgU.jpg]

I don't understand why there only my part my view that is being showed.

The is the CustomView in Xib

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `buttonView` isn't being clipped by a parent view or it isn't being covered by `xibView`?

Comment: I use the "Debug View Hierarchy" to check it. No elements are blocking the "buttonView". I try to use the code "cv.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)" and still didn't work. Even if I use the gesture code in the main UIView, it still didn't respond touch events.

Comment: It's not surprising at all that `cv.frame.size` is zero. The code you posted makes no attempt to give the view a size. That's certainly the problem. That also means that `buttonView` *is* being clipped by its parent view just as I suggested.

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of being clipped at first time you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let cv = CustomView()
self.view.addSubview(cv)
```

So cv has no size. So all of its subviews are outside its bounds. So they can be seen but they cannot be touched; a view outside is superview's bounds fails hit testing by default.

To help with this, say `cv.clipsToBounds = true`. Now you won't even *see* its subviews until you fix the problem.

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/sherlock-holmes-and-the-mystery-of-the-untappable-button/

Comment: I use "cv.clipsToBounds = true" and I really can't see the subviews now. I use the code cv.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 450, height: 450), but now only a part of the view appears. Looking to adapt the layout now.

Comment: Excellent, you're clearly on the right track now! It's best to use auto layout for everything, not frame.